# How can I get SQL to ignore a part of the WHERE clause when no result is found?

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry, I don't know how to ask this question without giving you the whole story:

Consider the following tables:

```
**users**
ID | name
1  | Shawn
2  | John
3  | Josh

**groups**
groupName | userID
groupA    | 1
groupA    | 2
groupB    | 1
```

This means that Shawn and John are part of group A, and Shawn is part of group B. Josh is part of no group at all.

What I want to do is to list every user and see to which group he belongs. Here is what I would try:

```
SELECT name, groupName FROM users, groups WHERE userID = ID GROUP BY name
```

Which outputs

```
name  | groupName
Shawn | groupA
John  | groupA
```

### Here is my problem

I can't see that Shawn is part of group B as well. Nor can I see Josh at all.

### my question

How can I get something like this instead?

```
name  | groupName
Shawn | groupA, groupB
John  | groupA
Josh  | none
```

Or at least something like this:

```
Shawn | groupA
Shawn | groupB
John  | groupA
Josh  |
```

I was thinking along theses lines:

```
SELECT name, groupName FROM users, groups WHERE (userID = ID GROUP BY name OR 1)
```

but I can't find the solution

Thanks you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MySQL-specific function [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT name, group_concat(groupName) 
FROM users, groups 
WHERE userID = ID GROUR BY name
```

Or, if you want all users to appear:

```
SELECT name, group_concat(groupName) 
FROM users LEFT JOIN groups ON userID = ID 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Also GROUP_CONCAT is supported by SQLite too.

Answer (score 10):

```
select name, groupName from 
users left outer join groups on UserID = ID 
order by name
```

It will display nulls for group name when the user doesn't belong to any group.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a left join if you want to see the users without any groups. And you don't need GROUP BY if you have no aggregation functions.

```
SELECT u.Name, g.groupName 
FROM Users u 
LEFT JOIN Groups g 
ON u.ID = g.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY name tells the DB you want one result per name.  This clearly isn't what you want.

The last data you show is the easiest to get:

```
SELECT name, groupName FROM users u LEFT JOIN groups g ON u.ID = g.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Actually, I wish we had this in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact output:

```
name  | groupName
Shawn | groupA, groupB
John  | groupA
Josh  | none
```

Use:

```
SELECT name, 
  IFNULL(group_concat(groupName ORDER BY groupName SEPARATOR ', '), 'none') AS groupName
FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN groups ON (ID = userID)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY ID
```